# Resizing images keeping aspect-ratio?

Tags: croppie

I am using the last version of Jquery Croppie v2.6.2. Its possible to define Jquery croppie when resizable function is available, to keep the aspect-ratio... the relation between Width/Height? something like this 2:1 .e.g if I resize my image with 500x250 this it's good! but I dont want to change with the square and generate an image 400x250... but also 400x200? or 100x50? Keeping the scale 2:1 when I resize the image using the "square"?

Now I can make this:

[image]

Is it possible to keep relation Width/Height when I resize? In other words avoid the "square" can resize the image free without keepping relation between Width/Height... Do you know is it possible by Croppie configuration? Or how Can I update the Jquery Croppie Library to allow this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

set your viewport to a 2:1 ratio ie

```
     viewport: {
          width: 200,
          height: 100
        }
```

turn off the resizer... that is the little squares on the right and bottom that allow you to change the width and height separately thus changing the aspect ratio. Croppie will still allow you to zoom in on the image.

```
    enableResize: false,
```